# Error while compiling (possibly including more than one time a function)

Tags: c, include

I'm doing a project for school, so I need to compile it with:

```
gcc hide.c stegano.c -o hide -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror
```

But then I get this errors:

```
/tmp/ccDME1jC.o: In function `calculate_n':
stegano.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `calculate_n'
/tmp/ccQxPZJu.o:hide.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccDME1jC.o: In function `tam_msg':
stegano.c:(.text+0x87): multiple definition of `tam_msg'
/tmp/ccQxPZJu.o:hide.c:(.text+0x87): first defined here
/tmp/ccDME1jC.o: In function `insere_msg':
stegano.c:(.text+0xe1): multiple definition of `insere_msg'
/tmp/ccQxPZJu.o:hide.c:(.text+0xe1): first defined here
/tmp/ccDME1jC.o: In function `copia':
stegano.c:(.text+0x201): multiple definition of `copia'
/tmp/ccQxPZJu.o:hide.c:(.text+0x201): first defined here
/tmp/ccDME1jC.o: In function `esconde_msg':
stegano.c:(.text+0x274): multiple definition of `esconde_msg'
/tmp/ccQxPZJu.o:hide.c:(.text+0x274): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The program code is like this, I think that the error is probably in the include's so I hid the actual code:

The program hide.c is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stegano.c"
//code//
```

Then it calls stegano.c, that contains all the actual function used in hide.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stegano.h"
//code//
```

And the header file stegano.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef unsigned char Byte;

void calculate_n(char name[MAX], int* n, int* x);
int tam_msg(char name[MAX]);
void insere_msg(int size, char name[MAX], Byte* v);
void copia(Byte* v1, Byte *v2, int size);
void esconde_msg(Byte* msg, char name1[MAX], char name2[MAX]);
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caused by this:

```
#include "stegano.c"
```

this will pull all the function definitions in `stegano.c` into `hide.c`. Meaning the `stegano.c` and `hide.c` now define the same functions. This will produce the *multiple definition* errors you see when you attempt to (compile and) link.

Include the header file instead:

```
#include "stegano.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `#include "stegano.c"`. Include the `stegano.h` file instead.

By including the `.c` file you basically try to compile the code from that file twice (once when including it and once when compiling the file directly) and thus both `stegano.o` and `hide.o` will contain the same functions which will break in the linking phase.